# EditText contextual behaviour in Action Bar

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

In the API Demos (level 17), there is a demo: Views/Search View/Action Bar

Click on the search icon and enter some text.

Now, I would like to bring up the contextual bar that shows the copy and paste icons, but this seems impossible.

Instead, you can only bring up the floating Paste button (after some hit-and-miss long-press magic).

Occasionally, it seems possible to highlight/select one of the words, but then nothing can be done with this selection.  This seems like a bug.

However, regardless of the bug, what is the expected behaviour regarding displaying the contextual bar of the copy and paste icons?

Note: tested on a Nexus 4 running stock 4.2.2.